# gitignore still including dll files

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a solution with 5 projects. I am using BitBucket for source control.
I have the following in my .gitignore main root

```
# Compiled source #
###################

*.com
*.class
*.dll
*.exe
*.o
*.so

# Packages #
############
# it's better to unpack these files and commit the raw source
# git has its own built in compression methods
*.7z
*.dmg
*.gz
*.iso
*.jar
*.rar
*.tar
*.zip
```

However everytime I rebuild the solution, I get changes in my visual studio Team Explorer and I see a list of .dll and .pdb files produced.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you commit the DLL files before? The `.gitignore` file only regards files which are not part of the repository.

Comment: Do the previous commits contain the .dll and .pdb files?  If so, .gitignore has no effect on them.  In that case you would remove them (`git rm`) and commit.  Once the file is not present *and* a .gitignore path matches it, git will pass over it in listing untracked changes and will resist `git add`ing it

Comment: @C-Otto - That's not exactly right. The ignore mechanism is ineffective on paths that are present in the HEADs index.  If the file is elsewhere in the repository, gitignore can still work.

Comment: Hi, Thanks it worked. I removed the files from the repository. I thought when I add the .extension git would automatically remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Did you clear the git cache after changing your gitignore?

`git rm --cached .`

will clear the cache and any old ignore rules. After that, your new rules should take effect for all new commits.

Obviously, this won't effect commits that have already been made.

Comment: I was able to use "git rm --cached <pathToFolder> -r" to recursively remove files previously checked in  and now dll and pdb files contained in those folders no longer show up when committing changes.